# Letter spacing in wxpython widgets

Tags: fonts, wxpython, label, spacing

There's a method to set the "letter spacing" for a `wx.TextCtrl`? (or another widget where I can show a small phrase)

Or is a property of the `wx.Font`?

Or is a inherent property of the font face I'm using?

A work-around I could implement is to write my custom control (maybe derived from RichTextCtrl) where I draw each character one by one, and add the selected spacing between them. But then it would be a lot less efficient to calculate (giving an example) the area of the text. This is rather simple with a ClientDC.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe this is a feature of any of the text controls or their variants. You could set the `wx.Font` to a monospace font, but that's probably about as good as you can get going the "automatic" way. I would recommend drawing it yourself if that's really what you need.